# C errors causing huge stress on me

Tags: c, arrays, function, turbo-c

I've been playing around with the code below just trying to get it to compile with the Borland compiler (It's the compiler I have to use - I'd much prefer to use GCC on Linux but here we are) but having no luck - can anyone see any obvious flaws?

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
float money() {
  float wages[SIZE], rise, total;  // where i is initaliser
  float percent = 0.2;
  int i = 0, j;
  for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) { 
    wages[i] = j; // Initializing each element seperately 
  }
  printf("Please enter the wages for each staff member\n");
  scanf("%d*%c", &wages[i]);
  rise = wages[i] * percent;
  total = rise + wages[i];
  printf("The new wage is $%f and appears in the %d array slot\n", total, j);
  return(0);
}

int main() {
  money();
  return(0);
}
```

**Compiler output**

> Warning W8004 payrise.c 8: 'i' is assigned a value that is never used in function money
>
> Warning W8065 payrise.c 23: Call to function 'money' with no prototype in function main

Comment: You are also new to StackOverflow.  This question is not a good question for this site because it is vague and it asks the internet to do your work for you.  **Ask a more specific question** that describes exactly what you are confused about, don't just say "I can't find my own bugs".

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Indent properly. `j` is uninitialised but used to initialise the `wages` array. `i` should not be used after the for loop - and actually you want to read input inside the loop...lots of issues. Maybe try something a bit easier?

Comment: Noted - im having trouble with all of it. the most annoying thing is that different compilers have different syntax acceptances, ie gcc works with pretty much all the code im writing where as Borland does not - and its Borland that i have to use for uni - so no luck there @HotLicks.

Comment: @HotLicks, Java is causing me stress, now what?

Comment: Maybe an art class?  Part of the attraction of programming to those who get "into" it is that even in the best of circumstances it's a bit of puzzle to work out why things behave the way they do.  If that's not your cup of tea then programming may not be your "thing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are both warnings; in this case the code referred to by the warnings is correct but it could have its style improved. You should be able to run the program even though it showed warnings; since there were no errors. (BTW you should have help files that came with the compiler; these will tell you what the warnings mean if you find the warning text unclear).

The first warning is because you have:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0;
```

i.e. the first setting of `= 0` is redundant because you immediately set it to `0` again.

The second warning is because you did not provide a prototype for `money`. You should declare the function as:

```
float money(void)
```

This makes it be a *prototype*, which has the effect that the compiler will flag an error if you later try to pass an argument to the function.

**However,** your code has other bugs which the compiler did not diagnose (or if it did, you didn't let us know).

Firstly you use `j` without initializing it. You should give it a value before using it.

Secondly, `scanf("%d*%c", &wages[i]);` is wrong. The format specifier for `float` is `"%f"`, not `"%d*%c"`. Also , `i` is out of range at this point (did you mean to have this code inside the loop?)